# Clustering variables by dependence

Tags: correlation, clustering, independence

Let consider a set of $p$ variables. I have a sample of size $n$ of these. I would like to determine groups of variables that depends on one another.

My current idea is to use [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) as a similarity measure and use a clustering algorithm.

- What clustering algorithm would be adapted for this purpose?
- Do you have any idea of an alternative approach?

Comment: From your current idea of using a distance correlation I presume your variables are univariate?

Comment: You surely can use any clustering method which can be used with Pearson r as a **similarity** measure. Those are methods except what are specifically and only for (squared) Euclidean distance (such as Ward's or centroid hierarchical methods), or those which analyze casewise data instead of a proximity matrix (such as k-means).

Comment: Notice that some algorithms converge faster than others (to the true clustering assuming your data is well-clustered, i.e. its underlying correlation matrix is (hierarchical) block diagonal (after a proper permutation of the data)). Prefer for instance Average or Complete Linkage to the Single Linkage. Warning: if your variables may follow heavy tailed distribution, prefer a correlation such as Spearman or Kendall coefficient.

Comment: @mic: Is your comment regarding the type of linkage motivated by computational performance issues only? In my case $n$ is relatively small ($\approx 50$).